# Cant get crosslinking to work in liquidSlider

Tags: jquery, html, web

I am developing a website and I cannot get the crosslinking feature of [Liquid Slider](http://liquidslider.com/) to work. I have crossLinking enabled. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Slide

```
            <div class="liquid-slider" id="main-slider">
            <div>
                <h2 class="title">Slide 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2 class="title">Slide 2</h2>
                <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2 class="title">Slide 3</h2>
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2 class="title">Slide 4</h2>
                <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Perhaps I need to give the DIVs a special ID?

Here is the section that I want the crosslinks in

```
        <div id="bottomBanner1" class="large-3 columns small-6 columns">
        <p class="bannerText"><a href="#1" data-liquidslider-ref="slider-id">DIDs</a>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomBanner2" class="large-3 columns small-6 columns">
        <p class="bannerText"><a href="#2" data-liquidslider-ref="slider-id">Orig</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomBanner3" class="large-3 columns small-6 columns">
        <p class="bannerText"><a href="#3" data-liquidslider-ref="slider-id">Term</a>I</p>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomBanner4" class="large-3 columns small-6 columns">
        <p class="bannerText"><a href="#3" data-liquidslider-ref="slider-id">E911</a></p>
    </div>
```

And here is the javascript to show that crosslinking is enabled.

```
    crossLinks:true,
hashLinking:false,
hashTitleSelector:".title"
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please be a little bit more describe. Since "It doesn't show anything" won't help us narrow down your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the links that you have the cross links in are pointing to the wrong id reference for your slider e.g.

```
...

<div id="bottomBanner2" class="large-3 columns small-6 columns">
    <p class="bannerText"><a href="#2" data-liquidslider-ref="slider-id">Orig</a></p>
</div>

...
```

Should be:

```
....

<div id="bottomBanner2" class="large-3 columns small-6 columns">
    <p class="bannerText"><a href="#2" data-liquidslider-ref="main-slider">Orig</a></p>
</div>

....
```

Notice the change in the `data-liquidslider-ref` to point to the correct id.